# New ASP.NET Core Web Application. Framework dropdown is disabled

Tags: visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to create a ASP.NET Core Web Application based on .NET Famework, but the dropdown-list for choosing framework is disabled. Why is that? Is it possible to enable it somehow and choose .Net Framework here?

[image]

Comment: VS Version Installed?

Comment: Visual Studio Community 2017, Version 15.7.3.

Answer (score 1):

So there are actually 2 templates...

Clicking new projects then go to the Web in the tree view refer to the image[image]

Using the template with in that .Net Core tree item will result in the screen you had.